# Recovering individual rows from backup MSSQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to recover only single row from backup, so far I have been successful by restoring whole backup and then copying that row...

I am not sure that this is the best way?

Comment: If there is reoccurring need for this I would change the app to keep an audit trail rather than deal with backups.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the only way. Far away from that. You can use SQL Server Import and Export Wizard or 3rd party tools that can be even more effective. For more information about both methods check the [Restore only specific data from SQL backups](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/restore-specific-data-from-sql-backups/) online article.

*Disclaimer: I work as a Product Support Engineer at ApexSQL*

Comment: But he has a backup file and wants to know whether he has to restore it. I don't believe that the import/export wizard will work on a .bak file, so yes, he has to restore it.

Comment: Please check out the article I referred to.

Answer (score -1):

It's not just the best, it's the only. Unless you go to some other mathod entirely, as Eric Scherrer says, by adding a trigger to your table and copying deleted rows to am Audit table. Youy can then recover deleted data from there.